# many to many relationship with custom keys and custom pivot table Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship between two tables : products and orders and the pivot is order_details
the pivot has two columns :

1. order_id reference on id in orders
2. sku reference on sku in products

I have defined the relation in the models of the tables like this :

**Order Model**

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class , 'order_details' , 'order_id' , 'sku');
    }
```

**Product Model**

```
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class , 'order_details' , 'sku' ,'order_id') ;
    }
```

so when I try to reach the products from Order model I get an empty array even if there was product related to this order

**order_details migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('order_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('quantity');
            $table->string('sku') ;
            $table->foreign('sku')->references('sku')->on('products')->cascadeOnDelete() ;
            $table->double('price') ;
            $table->double('price_before_discount') ;
            $table->foreignIdFor(Order::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**products migration**

*

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->double('price');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('quantity');
            $table->integer('discount')->default(0);
            $table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\Brand::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->unsignedFloat('rating')->default(0);
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('sku');
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(1);
            $table->boolean('is_available')->default(1);
            $table->foreign('sku')->references('sku')->on('skus')->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

- 

**orders migration**

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_number')->unique();
            $table->double('total');
            $table->string('status')->default('pending');
            $table->double('total_before_discount');
            $table->string('invoice')->nullable();
            $table->foreignIdFor(PromoCode::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->foreignIdFor(Customer::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->foreignIdFor(Address::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Show products table structure.

Comment: please share both orders and products table for better understanding why relationship not working.

Comment: @Win ok here it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code hope it will help you

**In Product Model:**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class , 'order_details' , 'sku' ,'order_id' , 'sku' , 'id');
}
```

**In Order Model**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class , 'order_details' , 'order_id' , 'sku' , 'id' , 'sku');
}
```